# I am trying to register a component but I am getting the error "Vue' is not defined no-undef"

Tags: vuejs3

```js
import OtpInput from "@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input";

Vue.component("v-otp-input", OtpInput);
```

Answer (score 3):

Vue 3 [registers components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#components-basics) from the app instance (created from `createApp()`):

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'

createApp(App)
  .component('v-otp-input', OtpInput)
  .mount('#app')
```

However, `vue-otp-input` looks like it's built for Vue 2, so your component will probably not work in Vue 3.